# exchange - kerio, smtp connector problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, exchange, email-server, kerio

First of all the details:

We have two servers.

```
1st - server 2003, exchange 2003. This is our main server
2nd - server 2008, KERIO server, This is our backup server
```

We want to forward a copy off all mail to the backup server.

Our domain is: company.local
 Our mail domain is: @company.my.com
 Our backup mail domain is: @company.my.com + we have an alias mail domain, so we can forward our mails.  The backup mail domain: @company.tmp.com

We have a central IT provider, so to send e-mail from excahnge we set: in the exchange system manager/administrative groups/firs.../ default smtp virtual server : derlivery/advanced: fully-qualified domain:  mainservername.company.local ;smart host: mail.provider.com

In the main server we create distribution groups for all users + create the @company.tmp.com contacts for all users and forward a copy of all mail to this distribution groups.
(the reason why we need distribution group is we need to forward mails two address / users in some cases)

We did already: In DNS settings under the company.local forward lookup zone we creat a new zone: company.tmp.com. Under this zone we creat a new MX record with the company.tmp.com

In the exchange system manager under the routing groups we create two smtp connector.

first: name: * ; forward all mail trougth.... mail.provider.com; local bridgehead: main server ; address space : *; scope: entire org;

second: name: backup; forward all mail... IP of our backup server; local bridgehead: main server; address space: @company.tmp.com ; scope: routing groups; allowe message realy... checked

**The problem is:**

I set the forwarding my mails to my tmp address.

First test:

```
   I send a test mail from my  **@company.my.com** to  **@company.my.com**

   I got the mail in my  @company.my.com box in exchange and i got the mail in KERIO too so forwarding is work well.
```

Second test:

```
  I send a test mail from a free provider on internet (gmail) to  @company.my.com I got the mail in exchage ( @company.my.com) but exchange not forward the mail to  KERIO.
```

The mail is in the "backup queue" and the stat of the mail is retry. In the smtp log i see the following: mail from:

I dont understand why can't forward all mail to the KERIO trougth smtp connector.

Thank you for the help; and sorry if my question is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the KERIO server settings. There is an option under the SMTP SERVER settings:

Block, if the send mail domain not in the DNS...uncheck...and voila.